# Query Graphite Metrics for specific data points

Tags: grafana, graphite

I want to query my graphite server to retrieve certain metrics.
I am able to query all data points between certain time period but my requirement is, I want to query data points of specific time of previous days.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Graphite Render API supports a number of arguments in order to make your query more specific. Specifically, the `from / until` arguments will be useful to you, you can read about them here: https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/render_api.html#from-until

edit: I should add that if you're using Grafana for visulaising your data, you can click+drag on the graph to select specific time ranges or use the timepicker in the top-right corner to choose `Custom` and set your range there.